# How do I determine through Docusign API, of my envelope was Wet Signed or Digitally signed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docusignapi

For every envelope that we generate in Docusign, the signer can sign digitally or use wet sign. In the case of wet signing, the user can choose to upload a copy or send through fax.
I would like to know the API (REST) call that would tell me the above details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone may have another way of doing this, but are you looking for a specific call for a known envelope or are you interested in Connect?  Either way, you're going to be looking at documents included in the envelope.

If you know a specific envelope is complete via some polling, you could use  GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents to get list of documents.

Connect automatically includes the document list in the notification to your web service.

With this data, you are of course looking for documents that weren't there when you sent the envelope.  Specific to Sign On Paper (DocuSign doesn't differentiate between upload vs fax back), the document provided back will be named Signed-on-Paper_ and a document GUID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I had implemented too. But I am still looking for a better way to do it. Thanks again.